# KTDatatables - Search within a column that has a template

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, metronic

I'm trying to use a search dropdown and it doesn't seem to work if it searches for a column that has a template on it. Also trying other types of input other than select but still to no avail. I've been trying to replicate what the demo file is doing and is still failing without any error from the console.

Here's my attempt:

```
$('#dashboard_import_shipments').KTDatatable({
          // snipped data
          columns: [
              {
                  field: "status",
                  title: "Status",
                  template: function(t) {
                      var a = {
                          1: {
                              title: "In-Transit",
                              class: " label-primary"
                          }

                          ,
                          2: {
                              title: "Docked",
                              class: " label-warning"
                          }

                          ,
                          3: {
                              title: "For GR# Processing",
                              class: " label-light-success"
                          }

                          ,
                          4: {
                              title: "Completed",
                              class: " label-success"
                          }

                          ,
                          5: {
                              title: "Cancelled",
                              class: " label-danger"
                          }
                      };
                      return '<span class="label font-weight-bold label-lg ' + a[t.status].class + ' label-inline">' + a[t.status].title + "</span>"
                  }
              },
          ]    
      }),
      $("#search_shipment_status").on("change", (function() {
          dashboardImportShipments.search($(this).val(), "status");
      }))
    }
};

<select id="search_shipment_status" class="form-control selectpicker" title="Select Status">
    <option value="1">In-Transit</option>
    <option value="2">Docked</option>
    <option value="3">For GR# Processing</option>
    <option value="4">Completed</option>
    <option value="5">Cancelled</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You nee to define the var **dashboardImportShipments**
On the examples, they use **datatable** as the variable, and then use it on the search

```
var datatable = $('#kt_datatable').KTDatatable({...})
```

and then

```
$('#kt_datatable_search_type').on('change', function() {
      datatable.search($(this).val().toLowerCase(), 'Type');
});
```

So it should be:

```
let dashboardImportShipments = $('#dashboard_import_shipments').KTDatatable({..})
```